# Change of pictures over and over by using setInterval

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, settimeout, setinterval

Below is a program that is to loop pictures with fade-in effect.

It includes this statement:

```
opacity = Number(window.getComputedStyle(abc).getPropertyValue("opacity"));
```

I understand that this statement assigns the opacity value of a window object to a variable `opacity`, but there is no such `opacity` variable declaration of any elements in the program!

When I remove this statement, it only shows the first picture...  And when I keep that statement, the program loops well with a fade-in effect.

Can anyone explain to me why such phenomenon happens?

Compare these two snippets:

1. With assignment to `opacity` (fading is working as expected):

```js
var opacity = 0;
var arrindex = 0;
var arr1 = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p1", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p2", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p3", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p4", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p5" 
];

setInterval(changepcs, 3000);

function changepcs() {
  if (arrindex == arr1.length) {
    arrindex = 0
  };
  let abc = document.getElementById("picture");
  let address = arr1[arrindex];
  abc.style.backgroundImage = `url(${address})`;
  abc.classList.remove("fadein");
  opacity = window.getComputedStyle(abc).getPropertyValue("opacity");
  abc.classList.add("fadein");
  arrindex++;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#picture {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 400px 400px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 80%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#picture.fadein {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="picture"></div>
```

2. Without assignment to `opacity` (no fading effect for second image):

```js
var opacity = 0;
var arrindex = 0;
var arr1 = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p1", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p2", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p3", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p4", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p5" 
];

setInterval(changepcs, 3000);

function changepcs() {
  if (arrindex == arr1.length) {
    arrindex = 0
  };
  let abc = document.getElementById("picture");
  let address = arr1[arrindex];
  abc.style.backgroundImage = `url(${address})`;
  abc.classList.remove("fadein");
  // opacity = window.getComputedStyle(abc).getPropertyValue("opacity");
  abc.classList.add("fadein");
  arrindex++;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#picture {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 400px 400px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 80%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#picture.fadein {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="picture"></div>
```

Comment: You would be better off just inserting all the images into your page, then triggering a fade in class. You can make them all overlay each other by making the parent a `grid` with a single cell and column, and giving every picture the same `column` and `row` index of `1`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i want to know why my codes don't work, where get wrong?

Comment: Your className never gets removed, so after fadein the fadein has completed, adding the class again does nothing as nothing changes. I highly suggest rethinking your structure here though. This is not a controllable way to make a fading gallery.

Comment: @somethinghere, many thanks for your comment.  And base on your comment I 've change to use classList to remove the "fadein" and add the "fadein" before the code "opacity = window.getComputedStyle()..", and it works now.  However, still have problem,  the browser can't render smoothly in its first loop...what is the problem?! and I have edit my program and question...

Comment: I made you a [mcve] - now you have seen several,please make one yourself next time you ask

Comment: You really help me a lot, sometimes i want to include the snippet, but i don't know how, and sometimes i also want to include some pictures and i don't know there is a tool that is placeholder....Thanks!

Comment: @mplungjan  So, do you have the same phenomenon as happen on me that only the  first picture is successfully loaded if the opacity statement is skipped, and it loops well if that opacity statement is kept?  Do you know the reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is not related to the *variable* `opacity`: you are right; it's value is never used after that assignment and is therefore unnecessary.

However, the call of `getComputedStyle(abc).getPropertyValue("opacity")` still makes the difference -- you can omit the call of `Number` and the *assignment* of this expression without any negative consequence, but the expression must stay.

This `getComputedStyle(abc).getPropertyValue("opacity")` is a complex API: it needs to render the document to know exactly what the opacity value is, since in general such CSS values can be influenced by a lot of CSS rules. My hunch is that the engine performs a paint cycle in order to compute the *real, rendered* value of this property. That means the execution of this call takes some time -- at least until after the next paint cycle. The side effect of this paint job is that the removal of the `fadein` class has now also been rendered. And that means that when that `fadein` class is *added* again, it really triggers the animation.

Without this `getComputedStyle(abc).getPropertyValue("opacity")` evaluation, the engine does *not* wait for a paint cycle. That means it has not yet effectuated the class removal when it adds the `fadein` class again. By consequence, nothing really changes -- the `fadein` class was still applied on the rendering when it is already "added" again. That means there is no animation.

I was a bit puzzled by this effect of that expression too. I would have explicitly waited for a paint cycle to happen with the call to `requestAnimationFrame` so to execute code right *before* the next paint cycle, and then schedule a callback again to get code to execute *after* the next paint job (before the next one). That would be the moment I would be sure the CSS class `fadein` had been removed in the *rendered* document and it would be the right time to add it again -- so triggering the animation.

Like so:

```js
var arrindex = 0;
var arr1 = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p1", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p2", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p3", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p4", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p5" 
];

setInterval(changepcs, 3000);

function changepcs() {
  if (arrindex == arr1.length) {
    arrindex = 0
  };
  let abc = document.getElementById("picture");
  let address = arr1[arrindex];
  abc.style.backgroundImage = `url(${address})`;
  abc.classList.remove("fadein");
  // Need to wait for a paint cycle to occur before 
  //    adding the CSS class again
  requestAnimationFrame(() => 
    requestAnimationFrame(() => abc.classList.add("fadein"))
  );
  arrindex++;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#picture {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 400px 400px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 80%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#picture.fadein {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="picture"></div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help.  So, as you said, that computed statement here in this program mainly is to providing some time interval to let the paint of the removal class of "fadein" to be painted out.  I had make a program that is use setTimeout to replace that computed statement and the program seems works too!  That's why i agree what you said.  In your program, I see you use RAF of RAF, I try to use 1 RAF instead, and the result is looping without fadein, I still don't understand this part, could you help to give me more explanation of this statement?  Thanks.

Comment: The RAF callback is called *before* the next paint cycle. This is too soon for our purpose, as we need a paint cycle to complete. By calling RAF inside that callback, giving it another callback, we are guaranteed that the second callback will be called *after* that paint cycle (before the next one). This is the soonest possible moment we can be sure the removal of the class was rendered. Of course `setTimeout` can also work, but that (by design) waits at least 4 milliseconds, which usually is a longer wait. Also, `setTimeout` does not give an *absolute* guarantee a paint cycle has happened.

Comment: Hi, I have just finished a coding of analog clock, and here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73483028/19324287  My problem is I don't know how to clear the "previous second lines".  I know one solution is to redraw the clock background each time of the setInterval, but i want to find a better solution since i think the only change thing is the time, there should be a method to make change of the time only, I have tried to use "ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over"", however, not successful....Perhaps you can help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your support to this question, it is highly believe as one of the answer here (from trincot) mention the statement: "getComputedStyle(abc).getPropertyValue("opacity")" provide some time interval that allows the paint of the removal of "fade-in" class here to be rendered.  To prove this, I try to replace the statement by using setTimeout statement: "setTimeout(()=>abc.classList.add("fadein"), 3000);" and the job is done.

```js
setInterval(changepcs,3000);
var opacity = 0;
var arrindex = 0;
var arr1 = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p1", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p2", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p3", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p4", 
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400?text=p5" 
];


function changepcs() {
if(arrindex == arr1.length){arrindex = 0};
let abc = document.getElementById("picture");
let address = arr1[arrindex];
abc.style.backgroundImage = `url(${address})`;
abc.classList.remove("fadein");
setTimeout(()=>abc.classList.add("fadein"), 3000);
arrindex++;
}
```

```css
body {
    height:100vh;
}

#picture {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 400px 400px;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    height: 80%;
    opacity: 0;
}

#picture.fadein {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="picture"></div>
</body>
```