# Using RequestAnimationFrame to create Fade in effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity, requestanimationframe

I know this can be done by using CSS transition, however this 2 seconds fade-in exercise has to be done by using requestAnimationFrame, below is my code, it shows the picture but no fade in effect, also the render process is not smooth.  Could you tell me where i get wrong and how to correct it? Thanks very much.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    #picture {
      background-image: url("p1.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: 400px 400px;
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
      height: 80%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="picture"></div>

  <script>
    var start = null;
    var abc = document.getElementById("picture")
    var opacity = 0;

    function step(timestamp) {
      if (!start) start = timestamp;
      var progress = timestamp - start;
      opacity = Number(window.getComputedStyle(abc).getPropertyValue("opacity"));
      if (opacity < 1) {
        opacity = opacity + 0.1;
        abc.style.opacity = opacity;
      }
      if (progress < 2000) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
      }
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet so that, in theory, your code could be demonstrated in the question. Unfortunately nothing seems to be happening, could you verify that your code is accurate?

Comment: @David thomas  Thanks. because a random image is needed to be inserted, in my code, in the part of css, the id #picture, there is an image file, p1.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script never sets the opacity of the `abc` element to 0, so the opacity you *read* in the `step` function, will always be 1.

So add this line in the initialisation part:

```
abc.style.opacity = 0;
```

This shows the animation, but as you add 0.1 in each step, the fading will be completed in 10 frames, which is quite fast.

Here is an adapted version of your code:

```js
function animateOpacity(abc, duration) {
    let start;
    
    function step(timestamp) {
        if (!start) start = timestamp;
        const opacity = (timestamp - start) / duration;
        abc.style.opacity = opacity;
        if (opacity >= 1) return;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

const abc = document.getElementById("picture");
abc.style.opacity = 0;
window.addEventListener("load", () => animateOpacity(abc, 3000));
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#picture {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/440u9.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="picture"></div>
```

Comment: Many thanks.  Yes, now i can see the fade in effect, however, the rendering is not smooth, it first load the upper half, then it take one second more to load the lower part, what is the problem? is because of the memory in my computer? or something else? Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fading, but with the loading of the image. Make sure then that your fading only starts when the image has loaded. On the other hand you must still make sure the image element starts with an opacity of 0 immediately (not after its load). I slightly updated my snippet (even though it didn't have the problem you describe), to make explicit that the animation only starts when the page has been loaded.

Comment: thanks for opinion, but how to do that? what codes i should add in order to fullfill what you said...

Comment: Check the update in the snippet I posted.

Comment: Many many thanks!  You have helped me a lot and seems completely solve my question...Thanks.  Since i am a beginner, i am now digesting your codes....Thanks.

Comment: I have another question and the link is https://stackoverflow.com/q/72991465/19324287 could u help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

---

The first is that you haven't set `opacity` in the CSS, so when you call `opacity = Number(window.getComputedStyle(abc).getPropertyValue("opacity"));` it starts out at `1` and never gets changed.

Add `opacity: 0` to the `#picture {` rules.

---

`window.requestAnimationFrame` will be called at **variable** intervals depending on how busy the browser is.

This is why you have a calculation for `progress` which tells you how far between "the start" and "2 seconds later" you are.

Your calculation for `opacity` **completely ignores `progress`**. It just increments by `0.1` every time you get a new frame.

Since frames are usually quite frequent, you get from `0` to `1` in 10 frames which is very quick.

You need to calculate `opacity` as a proportion of `progress` and not make it completely independent.

Comment: Hi Sir, Many thanks for your comment, i see in your above words, you mention that requestAnimationFrame will be called at variable intervals, what is variable intervals, i have search at google, but so far i cannot get it, is there any reference or could you give me some guides ....

Comment: It's English, not a technical term. An interval is a period of time. Something that is variable is not always the same.

Comment: Actually, i had done some search about the requestAnimationFrame, i got something similar as you mentioned above, it will be called and the call frequency depends on how busy the browser is.  But this arise me curious, if then would this possible to cause the animation sometimes delay (when the browser is busy) or sometimes faster? (when the browser is not busy and it can handle the missing frames when it is busy)